# Make a carousel infinite or repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

[image]

I'm still newbie and I'm still learning javascript/jquery. I have a code here for my carousel that I need to make it an infinite or repeating carousel, which means after the last carousel it will go back to carousel number 1.

Here is my code for both html and javascript.

Here is my code for the html:

```
<div class="featured-prods">
                <h6 class="container products-feature">Featured Products</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="2000">
                        <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                            <?php
                                $featured = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM featured_product");
                                while($feat = mysqli_fetch_array($featured)) {
                                    echo "<div class='item'>";
                                        echo "<div class='feature-container'>";
                                            echo "<div class='feature-text'>";
                                                echo $feat['title'];
                                            echo "</div>";
                                            echo "<img class='img-fluid' src=".$feat['image_url'].">";
                                            echo "<div class='feature-overlay'>";
                                                echo "<div class='feature-description'>".$feat['description']."</div>";
                                            echo "</div>";
                                        echo "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst"><</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is my code for javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
            var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
            var itemWidth = "";


            $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
                var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
                if (condition)
                    click(0, this);
                else
                    click(1, this)
            });
            ResCarouselSize();
            $(window).resize(function () {
                ResCarouselSize();
            });
            //this function define the size of the items
            function ResCarouselSize() {
                var incno = 0;
                var dataItems = ("data-items");
                var itemClass = ('.item');
                var id = 0;
                var btnParentSb = '';
                var itemsSplit = '';
                var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
                var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
                $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
                    id = id + 1;
                    var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
                    btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
                    itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
                    $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);
                    if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                        incno = itemsSplit[3];
                        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                    }
                    else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                        incno = itemsSplit[2];
                        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                    }
                    else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                        incno = itemsSplit[1];
                        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                    }
                    else {
                        incno = itemsSplit[0];
                        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
                    }
                    $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
                    $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                        $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
                    });
                    $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
                    $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");
                });
            }
            //this function used to move the items
            function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
                var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
                var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
                var translateXval = '';
                var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
                var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
                var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
                if (e == 0) {
                    translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
                    $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

                    if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                        translateXval = 0;
                        $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
                    }
                }
                else if (e == 1) {
                    var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
                    translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
                    $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

                    if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                        translateXval = itemsCondition;
                        $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
                    }
                }
                $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
            }
            //It is used to get some elements from btn
            function click(ell, ee) {
                var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
                var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
                ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I used slick before to do this: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
check the autoplay and getting started.

Comment: Thanks @mrdeadsven but i just want to edit this code. i don't want to add a new code.

Comment: Didn't read through your code but on my own one, I simply use `var next = $(current_slide).next(); if (next.length < 1) {next = $(slides).first();}` to make it repeating/infinite

Comment: Where will i put that? Inside where? @ggdx

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it. It's already done in bootstrap. You can refer to this official [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). No need to write additional JavaScript code unless you want to change something in the default one. And looking at your requirement you don't need to add a single line of JavaScript code.

Here is a sample

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT :** Since you are doing multi carousel you need to set the unique id on the carousel for optional controls on the single page. You can read more about that [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#example)

Comment: But the one i am doing is a multi carousel not a single one

Comment: What do you mean by multi carousel ?

Comment: Like in one row it displays like 6 items, instead of one

Comment: Oh okay. Can you try to edit your answer and show me how

Comment: Is your requirement to make a multiple carousel or to make the gallery to loop infinite ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172209/discussion-between-gwapo-and-lokesh).